# where is php.ini in joomla? (xampp installation)

Tags: php, xampp

I've googled for the past 30 minutes with no solution. I even searched 'php.ini' and all I get is ini.php files in my whole localhost/htdocts/mysites directory where my joomla is currently installed. The most recent answer I've found on the joomla forum is in july 2011 but I can't find the php.ini file where the people are saying it is. I even tried checking the installation directory before deleting it and turning on hidden files all with no luck. I have to change the settings to I stop getting uneccessary php error messages like the following right after installation:

```
Strict Standards: Static function JDatabase::test() should not be abstract in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\database\database.php on line 350

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 394

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 394

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\joomla_now\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php.ini` file belongs to your server configuration and is not part of Joomla. It seems you are using XAMPP - the file should be in your `C:\xampp\php` directory if you have XAMPP >= 1.7.0 and in `c:\xampp\apache\bin` for older versions.

Answer (score 2):

It should be found in xamppInstallationDir/PHP/PHP.ini for version 1.7.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the case *, you can get informed for any php.ini files loaded by your Joomla instance in the backend.
Simply go to System -> System Information -> PHP Information, where Joomla actually runs a phpinfo() function.
There you will be able to find all relevant information about the PHP configuration of your server environment.
Particularly for the php.ini you can look at these lines:

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path
- Loaded Configuration File
- Scan this dir for additional .ini files
- Additional .ini files parsed

*Unless phpinfo() is disabled in the server.